# Laravel Auth::onceBasic() remembering authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I'm trying to do something similar to here, but not for an API: [Fully disable cookies in Laravel 4 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415369/fully-disable-cookies-in-laravel-4-api/21717582#21717582)

Basically, I have a login section where users can download specific files and do other stuff. Before they can download, I want them to have to enter the username & password again as an additional security (think the same way some banks will do for you to download your statements.) My standard auth is working fine. I've managed to implement `Auth::onceBasic()` okay, but it's remembering I'm logged in and won't ask me more than once (even on closing the browser!).

That's when I found the above link about setting the `session.driver` to `array`, but it doesn't seem to work. I've turned off my primary login so that the `Auth::onceBasic()` is the only authentication and it is still remembering me when I visit the page more than once.

Here's my code:

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('downloads/{file}', 'DownloadsController@show')->before('auth.basic');
```

**filters.php:**

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    Config::set('session.driver', 'array');
    return Auth::onceBasic();
});
```

...and finally **DownloadsController:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd(Session::all());
}
```

my output shows the session as an array and empty, but it's still acting like it's authenticated so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've tested in chrome and firefox with the same results.

Comment: This isn't a problem with laravel, it's just the way basic auth is designed to work. Users remain logged in until the browser is closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295994/logging-out-with-http-basic-auth-in-laravel

Comment: @Jeemusu - okay, fair enough. doesn't make sense, but that seems to be the consensus from the linked question & it's linked resources. If you add an answer, will mark as solved. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively why not force the user to a separate login method every time they try to access that page. Instead of using laravels `auth::attempt`, create a new method to simply just check the credentials, and if it passes set a new session variable.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravels `Auth::onceBasic()` uses HTTP basic authentication, which isn't designed to handle your use case. With basic authentication the user will remain logged in until the browser is closed.

Comment: Your explanation is the exact contrary of the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication. Thanks for pointing this out.